# C# Httpclient Asp.net Core 2.0 on Kestrel Waiting, Lock Contention, high CPU

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a very simple API that have a singleton instance with many HTTPClients reused across the entire application.
The API is called, I create a list of tasks, each task call a client.
I use a CancellationToken and another task for a strict timeout.

```
public class APIController : Controller
{
    private IHttpClientsFactory _client;
    public APIController(IHttpClientsFactory client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var allTasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task<Response>>();
        foreach (var name in list)//30 clients in list here
        {
            allTasks.Add(CallAsync(_client.Client[name], cts.Token));
        }
        cts.CancelAfter(1000);
        await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(allTasks), Task.Delay(1000));
        //do something with allTasks 
    }
}
```

CallAsync is simple too, just use the client to call and wait for the answer.

```
 var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content, token);
```

Now this code works perfectly, after 1 second it returns then send the cancellation request to any task not yet returned.
The task list is around 30 Clients, so the API calls 30 endpoints any time is called, average response time of 800ms.

This application manage 3000 concurrent calls per second, so around **100k Httpclient calls are done per second**.

The problem is that there is some bottleneck in the HttpClient, in fact the CPU is always very high and I need around 80 (eigthy) 16 cores virtual machines with 32GB RAM to handle the traffic. There is clearly something wrong.

One hint I have is that the exact same code performed way better before updating my nugget packages to Asp.net Core 2.

I did a diagnostic on the server, nothing in my code is wrong, but seems like HttpClients clients are sort of waiting for each other or stuck.

[image]
[image]

There is really nothing else in the trace. 
I'm using a Factory for creating the single instance per endpoint:

```
  public class HttpClientsFactory : IHttpClientsFactory
{
    public static Dictionary<string, HttpClient> HttpClients { get; set; }

    public HttpClientsFactory()
    {
        HttpClients = new Dictionary<string, HttpClient>();
        Initialize();
    }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        HttpClients.Add("Name1", CreateClient("http://......"));  
        HttpClients.Add("Name2", CreateClient("http://...."));
        HttpClients.Add("Name3", CreateClient("http://...."));

    }

    public Dictionary<string, HttpClient> Clients()
    {
        return HttpClients;
    }

    public HttpClient Client(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            return Clients()[key];
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static HttpClient CreateClient(string endpoint)
    {
        try
        {
            var config = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                MaxConnectionsPerServer = int.MaxValue,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };
            var client = new HttpClient(config)
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000),
                BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint)
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return client;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in startup

```
 services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientsFactory, HttpClientsFactory>();
```

What's happening here, is a singleton for the HttpClient not good for the case?
Should I create an HttpClient instance per Thread instead? and how do I do that?

**UPDATE**

After days of testing I'm sure the timeout during the HTTPClient calls leave some connections open that brings to port exhaustion.
Any suggestion on how to avoid this?

Comment: My initial thought is that there are too many clients, and that has been known to cause problems. HttpClient was meant to have one client reused for the life of the application. From the factory method there doesn't seem to be much difference between the clients other than base url.

Comment: There is a limitation regarding outgoing connection number with HttpClient : please have a look to this blog entry - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timomta/2017/10/23/controlling-the-number-of-outgoing-connections-from-httpclient-net-core-or-full-framework/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are hitting the limit of what the operating system can do with HTTP requests, due to the way HTTP is designed to work. If you are using .NET framework (as opposed to dotnet core) then you can tweak how the operating system manages HTTP requests using the [`ServicePointManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx). Most HTTP servers and clients use `keep-alive`, which means they will reuse the same TCP connection for multiple HTTP requests. You can use the [`ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5f0atwd.aspx) function to get the [`ServicePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.aspx) instance for the connection to a specific host. Every HTTP request to the same host uses the same `ServicePoint` instance.

Try tweaking some of the values in the `ServicePoint` and see how it affects your application. For example `ConnectionLimit`, which controls how many parallel TCP connections will be used between the client and the server. While `keep-alive` will let you reuse an existing TCP connection for a new HTTP request, and `pipelining` (check if the server you are connecting to supports this using [`SupportsPipelining`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.supportspipelining.aspx)) lets you send multiple requests at the same time, HTTP requires the responses to come in the same order as requests. This means that an initial slow response will block all subsequent requests/responses. By having multiple TCP connections you can have multiple non-blocking HTTP requests in parallel. But ofcourse there is a downside, as you now have multiple TCP connections that will have to fight each other for network resources. So, tweak this value and see if it improves, but be careful!

So as mentioned above the real problem here is probably the HTTP protocol and how it can only really handle one request at a time. Fortunately there is a solution to this, in HTTP/2, unfortunately this is not well supported by asp.net yet. I haven't tried it, since the system I work on doesn't support it yet, but in theory it should allow you to send and receive multiple HTTP requests in parallel without blocking. Have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4870) which describes a way to get it to work.

**EDIT**

I completely missed that you are running on asp.net core 2.0. In that case you [don't have access to `ServicePointManager`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10727). But if you only need to run on windows then you can install the [`WinHttpHandler`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/) nuget and set the [`MaxConnectionsPerServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.winhttphandler.maxconnectionsperserver%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property. But if you are using `WinHttpHandler` then I would recommend trying HTTP/2 and seeing if that improves things for you.

**EDIT2**

We just discovered an issue where POST requests took twice the time that GET requests, although the rest of the request was exactly the same. We discovered the issue from an off-site location when connecting localhost to an on-premise server, so the ping was much higher than it normally is. This indicated that two round-trips were made when doing POST, while only one round-trip was made when doing GET. The solution was these two lines:

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Maybe that will help for you too?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already using HttpClientHandler() => MaxConnectionsPerServer = int.MaxValue it's in the second code block at the bottom. I reduced the power of the virtual machines increasing the number instead (from 80 D5V2 sixteen cores to 120 D4V2 eight cores) and seems a little better, maybe I'm really hitting the OS limits even if seems so low, the CPU is not over 15% and everything slows down or I see in the Chrome console ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
I'll investigate HTTP/2, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L433) of HttpClient you can see that if Timeout property is not equals to Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, HttpClient creates CancellationTokenSource with a timeout for each request:

```
        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        bool disposeCts;
        bool hasTimeout = _timeout != s_infiniteTimeout;
        if (hasTimeout || cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            disposeCts = true;
            cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _pendingRequestsCts.Token);
            if (hasTimeout)
            {
                cts.CancelAfter(_timeout);
            }
        }
```

Looking at the [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs,460) of CancelAfter() we can see that it internally [creates](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs,1bf5ec1912de006c) System.Threading.Timer object:

```
public void CancelAfter(Int32 millisecondsDelay)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (millisecondsDelay < -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("millisecondsDelay");
        }

        if (IsCancellationRequested) return;

        // There is a race condition here as a Cancel could occur between the check of
        // IsCancellationRequested and the creation of the timer.  This is benign; in the 
        // worst case, a timer will be created that has no effect when it expires.

        // Also, if Dispose() is called right here (after ThrowIfDisposed(), before timer
        // creation), it would result in a leaked Timer object (at least until the timer
        // expired and Disposed itself).  But this would be considered bad behavior, as
        // Dispose() is not thread-safe and should not be called concurrently with CancelAfter().

        if (m_timer == null)
        {
            // Lazily initialize the timer in a thread-safe fashion.
            // Initially set to "never go off" because we don't want to take a
            // chance on a timer "losing" the initialization ---- and then
            // cancelling the token before it (the timer) can be disposed.
            Timer newTimer = new Timer(s_timerCallback, this, -1, -1);
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_timer, newTimer, null) != null)
            {
                // We lost the ---- to initialize the timer.  Dispose the new timer.
                newTimer.Dispose();
            }
        }


        // It is possible that m_timer has already been disposed, so we must do
        // the following in a try/catch block.
        try
        {
            m_timer.Change(millisecondsDelay, -1);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // Just eat the exception.  There is no other way to tell that
            // the timer has been disposed, and even if there were, there
            // would not be a good way to deal with the observe/dispose
            // race condition.
        }

    }
```

When creating Timer object it [takes a lock](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,557) on a singleton TimerQueue.Instance

```
    internal bool Change(uint dueTime, uint period)
    {
        bool success;

        lock (TimerQueue.Instance)
        {
            if (m_canceled)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("ObjectDisposed_Generic"));

            // prevent ThreadAbort while updating state
            try { }
            finally
            {
                m_period = period;

                if (dueTime == Timeout.UnsignedInfinite)
                {
                    TimerQueue.Instance.DeleteTimer(this);
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (FrameworkEventSource.IsInitialized && FrameworkEventSource.Log.IsEnabled(EventLevel.Informational, FrameworkEventSource.Keywords.ThreadTransfer))
                        FrameworkEventSource.Log.ThreadTransferSendObj(this, 1, string.Empty, true);

                    success = TimerQueue.Instance.UpdateTimer(this, dueTime, period);
                }
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

If you have lots of concurrent HTTP requests you can face [lock convoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_convoy) problem. This issue is described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13083) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/14527).

To confirm this try to debug you code using Parallel Stacks window in VS or use syncblock WinDbg command from SOS extension.

Comment: Had a similar issue with a large amount of concurrent requests with timeouts going through the HttpClientFactory locking up the entire application, and this was the cause.  We removed our timeouts and the issue completely vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `MaxConnectionsPerServer = Environment.ProcessorCount`.

With `MaxConnectionsPerServer = int.MaxValue` your program creates/uses too many threads that compete with each other for CPU resources. So switching between the threads plus threads overhead slow down performance.